# Probabilities, nails

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[image]
The table shows the lengths of nails contained in a bag.
Tom takes a nail at random , then he records it length and replace it back in the bag , then he takes another nail at random . 
Find the probability that:

1) The two nails have length $60$ mm

2) The nails have total length $80 $ mm

My turn :
The events are independent then
1) $$\frac{2}{20}\times \frac{2}{20}= \frac{1}{100}$$
2) The sum of all probability = $$\frac{1}{4}$$
Is the solution correct?

Comment: How did you get $\frac14$?

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is correct.

Now for the second, you will see that the total length is 80mm iff the two nails are of lengths 30 and 50 or 40 and 40.

The probability of these draws is:
$\frac{8}{20} \cdot \frac{5}{20} \cdot 2 +\frac{4}{20} \cdot \frac{4}{20}=\frac{6}{25} $.

We multiplied by 2 because the order will matter.